# How do i move a screenshot from an extension to a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screen-capture

So the idea goes like this... all i want to do is call an extension background page as soon as a specific content script is loaded. (in this case when a page is loaded) I have something like this in my content script.

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "screenshot"});
port.postMessage({request: "screenshot"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = msg.response;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

And something like this in my background.js page

```
function takeScreenshot(){
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(img) {
        return img;

    });
}
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "screenshot");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.request == "screenshot"){
        port.postMessage({response: takeScreenshot() });
    }
    });
});
```

But i am having no luck... I get the image to show up on the body but it doesnt actually pass the image when returning img from takeScreenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to achieve synchronization between synchronous and  asynchronous events in [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)

a) [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) is asynchronous

b)  [port.postMessage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) is synchronous

When `port.postMessage({response: takeScreenshot() });` is called it does not wait for *takeScreenshot()* [**call back**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) i.e; `return img;` so an empty JSON object is sent to [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Avoid it with [posting message](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) after [call back](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) returns

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "screenshot");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.request == "screenshot"){
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{format:"jpeg",quality:100},function(img) {
        //post message only after call back return with Data URL
        port.postMessage(img);
        });
    }
    });
});
```

**Working Version Demonstration**

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Screen Shot Demo",
"description":"This demonstrates Screen Shot API",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1",
"permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"],
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

***background.js***

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "screenshot");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.request == "screenshot"){
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{format:"jpeg",quality:100},function(img) {
        //post message only after call back return with Data URL
        port.postMessage(img);
        });
    }
    });
});
```

***myscript.js*** (contentscript)

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "screenshot"
});
port.postMessage({
    request: "screenshot"
});
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! This doesnt seem like something that is basic knowledge and I would never have guessed or had even began to look in that direction. The only thing i had to change was taking out the {format:"jpeg",quality:100}, which for some reason placed an [object Object] in the src attribute of my img element.